Physical device detection or run emulator issue for flutter project
Actually I am facing two type of issues:

If I load a android project in Android studio then physical device not detecting sometime(Mostly first time after start laptop). Then I need to change the only system variable path sequence(Not modify or delete) inside Environment Variables. After that restart laptop solve my issue.
If I load Flutter project then device not detecting. But "adb devices" command show the actual device but "flutter devices" not showing any physical devices. And unable to run or debug any flutter project. I have tried many solutions suggested by Google or ChatGPT but still facing problem.

Follow all instruction by Google and ChatGPT.
